# Ajax Post with Two Forms in Laravel

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel-5

So, I'm having trouble sending a post request through ajax in Laravel 5. 
I have 2 forms in a view, and one of them is making an ajax call.

First, the routes:

```
Route::post('partidoBoostFree', 'PartidoController@boostFree');
Route::resource('partido', 'PartidoController');
```

Here's the Form that makes the call in the view:

```
<div class="col-md-4 boostPanel">

        <div class="panel-body">

            <div class="input-group">
                {!! Form::open([  'url' => 'partidoBoostFree', 'id' => 'guardaBoostFree', 'method' => 'POST' ]) !!}
                 <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{{ Session::getToken() }}}">


                {!! Form::hidden('id_boost_free', $partidoBoost->id, ['id' => 'id_boost_free']) !!}
                {!! Form::text('juegatela', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'juegatela', 'placeholder' => 'Puntos a jugar']) !!}
            </div>

            {!! Form::submit('Juégatela', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary form-control', 'id'=>'juegatelaSbmt', 'disabled' => 'disabled']) !!}
            {!! form::close() !!}

        </div>
</div>
```

Here's the JS:

```
$('#juegatelaSbmt').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    $.ajax({
      url: '/partidoBoostFree',
      method: 'POST',
      data: {
        'idPartido' : $('#id_boost_free').val(),
        'puntos' : $('#juegatela').val(),
        '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val()
      },
      success: function(data){
        $('.boostPanel .panel-body').html(data);
      }
    })

  });
```

And finally the Controller:

```
public function boostFree(){

        if ( Request::ajax() ){

            $data = Input::all();

            if( $data[puntos] > 0 && $data[puntos] < 4 ){

                if( $this->partidoRepo->getPartido_Usuario( $data[idPartido], Auth::user() )  ){
                    $apuesta = $this->apuestaRepo->postApuestaFree( $data[idPartido], Auth::user(), $data[puntos] );

                    if($apuesta){
                        return "<div class='alert alert-info' role='alert'>
                                <p>Te la jugaste. Suerte!!!</p>
                                </div>";
                    }else{
                        flash()->error('Hubo un problema, intentalo más tarde');
                    }
                }else{
                    //Regresa mensaje de que haga la quiniela por lo menos para el partido
                }
            }else{
                //Regresa un mensaje de seleccionar el min o máximo de puntos a jugar.
            }
        }
    }
```

Here's the funny thing, when i make that ajax action in the inspector i got this:

[image: Response 500]

But, if I comment the boostFree() function, i get:
[image: Response200]

And the problem is, that no matter is a 200 or 500 I get from Laravel a
**MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 207** Error

I tried almost everything, put the token in the headers, changing the post action to get (I know that this isn't going to work), change "type" to "method" in the .ajax function.

Hope somebody can help me, i really appreciate it.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: It looks like your route is configured to post to `partidoBoostFree` and your form is posting to `/partidoBoostFree`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Laravel is giving you the `MethodNotAllowed` exception because you are trying to post to `/partidoBoostFree` but the route is set up on `partidoBoostFree`.  You should use the artisan command line tool to check your routes:

```
php artisan route:list
```

This will give you a listing of all your routes and you can verify that they are set up how you wanted.

I would also recommend naming your routes, so that you can reference them by name rather than having to remember the exact URLs.

To create a named route:

```
Route::post('/partidoBoostFree', array(
    'as'    =>    'partidoBoostFree',
    'uses'  =>    'PartidoController@boostFree'
));
```

To reference a named route:

```
{{ route('partidoBoostFree') }}
```

This is a good way to go because you can change the route's URL at any time without breaking your code that references that route as long as you referenced it by name and the name doesn't change.

Comment: Noup... it doesn't work, also i changed the ulr, tried with / and without it... I alreadey checked the route list and it has a POST verb. I really don't know what it is...

Comment: Alright, i used PostMan to verify the Request and now throws me a TokenMismatchException Error... maybe is going that way, but how do i correct them, assume that the errors appears by having two forms???

Answer (score 0):

set up something like 
url: window.location.origin+'/your-url';

For more:
Visit this link
http://sumanshresth.com.np/using-ajax-in-laravel/